# Difference Between two dates columns

Tags: python

I have to find difference between two date columns in python dataframe and to compare whether difference is greater than 120 or not

if working_data['CLAIMS_EVENT_DATE'] - working_data['LAST_LAPSED_DATE'] > 120:

I got below Error

invalid_comparison
    .format(dtype=left.dtype, typ=type(right).**name**))

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

Comment: what about `(working_data['CLAIMS_EVENT_DATE'] - working_data['LAST_LAPSED_DATE']).dt.days >120`

Comment: working_data is a dataframe name. CLAIMS_EVENT_DATE and LAST_LAPSED_DATE are column names

Answer (score 1):

If compare both get timedeltas, so for compare are possible 2 solutions - compare days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) if need test if at least one value match condition:

```
s = (working_data['CLAIMS_EVENT_DATE'] - working_data['LAST_LAPSED_DATE'])

if (s.dt.days > 120).any():
    print ('At least one value is higher')
```

Or compare by `Timedelta`:

```
if (s > pd.Timedelta(120, unit='d')).any():
    print ('At least one value is higher')
```

If need fitler rows use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = working_data[s.dt.days > 120]
```

Or:

```
df = working_data[s > pd.Timedelta(120, unit='d')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Convert both columns to datetime format
working_data['CLAIMS_EVENT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(working_data['CLAIMS_EVENT_DATE'])
working_data['LAST_LAPSED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(working_data['LAST_LAPSED_DATE'])

#Calculate the difference between the days
working_data['Days'] = (working_data['LAST_LAPSED_DATE']                           
                        - working_data['CLAIMS_EVENT_DATE']).days

#Create a column 'Greater' and check whether difference is greater than 120 or not
working_data.loc[working_data.Days <= 120, 'Greater'] = 'False' 
working_data.loc[working_data.Days > 120, 'Greater'] = 'True'
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The TypeError is due to the comparison between different datatypes.